# which is executed first between setTimeout and setInterval?

Tags: javascript, node.js

As per  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals), the callbacks in `setTimeout()` function are executed only when the stack on the main thread is empty.Is this  same for `setInterval()`  function? If yes then when both these function are present then which will be executed first?

I am using node.js environment I am getting some inconsistent result with below code

```
var i = 0;
function cal(){
     i++; 
console.log(i);
if(i == 2) clearInterval(inter);
}
const inter = setInterval(cal,2000);

setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log('Hello');
},2000)
```

the output I am getting is

```
1
Hello
2
```

**but If I run below code**

```
setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log('Hello');
},2000)

var i = 0;
function cal(){
     i++; 
console.log(i);
if(i == 2) clearInterval(inter);
}

const inter = setInterval(cal,2000);
```

**the output I am getting is**

```
Hello
1
2
```

Comment: What's the problem? You start the interval before the timeout in the first case, so the interval logs first. You start the timeout before the interval in the second case, so the interval logs second... You would have to start the interval and timeout at exactly the same nanosecond in order to determine "which came first".

Comment: In first case it should log 1 2 hello . the entire  setInterval must be be executed before starting timeout

Comment: That's not how `setInterval` works.

Comment: @sagarcaset "_the entire setInterval must be be executed before starting timeout_" - What do you mean by _"entire setInterval"_? Each call to `cal` will log `i` only once.

Comment: @HereticMonkey as per MDN main thread should be free for callback in  setTimeout() to be executed

Comment: @sagarcaset the main thread is free between the two executions of your interval, at which point the timeout runs

Comment: `setInterval` schedules actions to be taken at certain times. It does not block the thread during the interval, so `setTimeout` is free to run and prints "Hello". Approximately 2000ms later, `setInterval` runs the second scheduled function call, prints `2`, and clears the interval. I suggest reading that article I posted. The answers go into much more detail than I can in a comment.